# Testing strategies for testing a Scheduler

Tags: unit-tests, scheduling

We have developed an in-house Scheduler which is based on [Rate-monotonic scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling). We have 6 tasks (5 actual tasks and 1 idle task). Our scheduler works on 1msec timer interrupt. Before sending it out in real world, We want to test it thoroughly.

What are the best and/or commonly used strategies for testing a Scheduler?

One thing we performed was added functions which require very high processing time in each tasks and checked whether scheduler still switches on given deadline or not. But I feel this is not enough to gain the confidence.

Comment: Related: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6571/testing-a-system-with-scheduled-event-driven-data-changes

Comment: @user246 I would say very broadly.Reason is this system is working at frequency of 1mSec plus Answers for the question won't satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some ideas from similar tests:

1. Randomize, you are not smarter then the designer so don't try to find the hole in the design- randomize your tests
2. Vary load conditions from light to 100%+ on each task and on all of them together
3. Look for producer-consumer situations that can hang tasks
4. Look for accesses to peripherals and IO

The bottom line is that you can't test your scheduler directly (at least no cost-effectively) so you have to exercise it from the outside.